# Transform structure of Spark DF. Create one column or row for each value in a column. Impute values

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DF with the following structure:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| user| time                  | counts |
+--------------------------------------+
|   1 | 2018-06-04 16:00:00.0 | 5      |
|   1 | 2018-06-04 17:00:00.0 | 7      |
|   1 | 2018-06-04 17:30:00.0 | 7      |
|   1 | 2018-06-04 18:00:00.0 | 8      |
|   1 | 2018-06-04 18:30:00.0 | 10     |
|   1 | 2018-06-04 19:00:00.0 | 9      |
|   1 | 2018-06-04 20:00:00.0 | 7      |
|   2 | 2018-06-04 17:00:00.0 | 4      |
|   2 | 2018-06-04 18:00:00.0 | 4      |
|   2 | 2018-06-04 18:30:00.0 | 5      |
|   2 | 2018-06-04 19:30:00.0 | 7      |
|   3 | 2018-06-04 16:00:00.0 | 6      |
+--------------------------------------+
```

It was obtained from an event-log table using the following code:

```
ranked.groupBy($"user", sql.functions.window($"timestamp", "30 minutes"))
.agg(sum("id").as("counts"))
.withColumn("time", $"window.start")
```

As can be seen looking at the `time` column, not all 30-min intervals registered events for each user, i.e. not all `user` groups of frames are of equal lengths. I'd like to impute (possibly with `NA`'s or `0`'s) missing time values and create a table (or RDD) like the following:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+ 
| user| 2018-06-04 16:00:00 | 2018-06-04 16:30:00 | 2018-06-04 17:00:00 | ... |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|   1 | 5                   | NA (or 0)           | 7                   | ... |
|   2 | NA (or 0)           | NA (or 0)           | 4                   | ... |
|   3 | 6                   | NA (or 0)           | NA (or 0)           | ... |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The transpose of the table above (with a `time`, column, and a column for the counts of each `user`) would theoretically work too, but I am not sure it would be optimal spark-wise as I have almost a million different users.

How can I perform a table re-structuring like described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each time window appears for at least one user, a simple pivot would do the trick (and put null for missing values). With millions of rows, it should be the case.

```
val reshaped_df = df.groupBy("user").pivot("time").agg(sum('counts))
```

In case a column is still missing, you could access the list of the columns with `reshaped_df.columns` and then add the missing ones. You would need to generate the list of columns that you expect (`expected_columns`) and then generate the missing ones as follows:

```
val expected_columns = ???
var result = reshaped_df
expected_columns
    .foreach{ c => 
        if(! result.columns.contains(c)) 
            result = result.withColumn(c, lit(null))
    }
```

Comment: How can I reasonably impute the missing timewindows?

Comment: You could iterate over the list of columns you expect to find, and add them if they are missing. I edited the answer and added a little bit of code. I don't know what columns you expect though so you still need to generate the list ;-)